# Google Map : Add symbol on region & zone

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I am working on one application which is having google map developed but I am newbe to google map. Now I am having two queries :

1. In local, when I run solution, it is showing developer mode and when I try to run for direction, it is show error message in Javascript Console : 'Directions Service: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key'. How to solve this in developer mode? Code is given below for reference :

   ```
   function initMap() {
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
       //suppressMarkers: true,
       polylineOptions: {
           strokeWeight: 8,
           strokeOpacity: 1.0,
           strokeColor: "#8b0000"
       },
       draggable: true
   });

   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService({});
   var onChangeHandler = function () {
       calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
   };


   }

   function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
   var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
   var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
   if (start != -1 && end != -1) {
       directionsService.route({
           origin: start,
           destination: end,
           travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
           unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
           provideRouteAlternatives: true,

   }, function (response, status) {
       if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
           directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       } else {
           window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
       }
   });


   }
   }
   ```
2. As another task, I will have to display state/region and zone vise one icon. How to do that?? As I am newbe not able to get it. For city, with the help of lat-long, I am able to show icon but not getting for state/region and Zone vise.

TIA.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: I have added some code lines for reference